# How to use slice method in data-table, vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatable, slice

I have a vue app where Im using v-data table. I'm displaying some data in the table but I want to use slice method to change the way to display it.

Here is what I display in my table:

[image]

Here is what I want to have:

[image]

I know that I should use the slice method to achieve this result but I dont know how to use slice method with v-data-table. I need help with applying this method.

table.js

```
     <v-data-table
                v-model="selected"
                dense
                :headers="headers"
                :items="workHours"
                show-select
              > </v-data-table>
```

script - headers

```
 headers: [
      { text: 'Start date', value: 'startDate' },
      { text: 'End date', value: 'endDate' },

    ]
  }),
```

script - methods

```
 methods: {
   
    async getworkHours() {
      let result = await this.sendAjaxWithParams(this.ajaxURLs.getworkHours);
      this.workHours= result.result.items;
    },
```

api.js

```
router.post('/getworkHours', (req, res) => {
  var items = [
    {
      startDate: '2018-01-05T09:00:00Z',
      endDate: '2018-01-05T16:45:00Z',
    },
    {
      startDate: '2018-01-03T07:00:00Z',
      endDate: '2018-01-03T19:00:00Z',
  
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function to format your date as you want:

```
function formatHoursMinutes(str) {
    const date = new Date(str)
    const hours = ('0' + date.getHours()).slice(-2)
    const minutes = ('0' + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2)
    return `${hours}:${minutes}`
}
```

And then right after you get the workHours you can mutate it like this:

```
this.workHours.forEach(item => {
    item.startDate = formatHoursMinutes(item.startDate)
    item.endDate = formatHoursMinutes(item.endDate)
})
```

---

You can also create new properties instead of mutating the original ones:

```
this.workHours.forEach(item => {
    item.startDateHoursMinutes = formatHoursMinutes(item.startDate)
    item.endDateHoursMinutes = formatHoursMinutes(item.endDate)
})
```

And then in your headers:

```
headers: [
    { text: 'Start date', value: 'startDateHoursMinutes' },
    { text: 'End date', value: 'endDateHoursMinutes' },
]
```

Comment: one thing, I should added this before formatHoursMinuted :) 

this.technicianWorkhours.forEach(item => { item.startDate = this.formatHoursMinutes(item.startDate); item.endDate = this.formatHoursMinutes(item.endDate); });